# Find the value of $(2n^2+1)^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, conic-sections

> A hyperbola has centre at origin$(O)$ and foci at $S_1,S_2$ and the line containing its transverse axis has a variable slope $x(\ne0)$. Let, $M$ be a parabola with its vertex at $C$ and focus at $S$ and its axis lies along the $X$ axis. Consider a circle $N$, passing through $S$ and at centre $C$. Now two common tangents of $M$ and $N$ are drawn from $S_1$ and $S_2$ such that they intersect each other at a point $P$. Area of $\triangle PS_1S_2,\triangle CS_1S_2$ and $\triangle SS_1S_2$ are $\triangle,\triangle_1$ and $\triangle_2$ respectively. If there exists a $n(\in\mathbb{R^+})$ such that,

$$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\left[\sqrt{\frac{((OC)^2+(OS)^2)\triangle}{{\triangle_1}^2+{\triangle_2}^2}}\right] dx}{\int_{-n}^{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}\left[\sqrt{\frac{((OC)^2+(OS)^2)\triangle}{{\triangle_1}^2+{\triangle_2}^2}}\right] dx+\int_{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}^{n}\left[\sqrt{\frac{((OC)^2+(OS)^2)\triangle}{{\triangle_1}^2+{\triangle_2}^2}}\right] dx}=1$$

> where $[.]$ denotes the greatest integer function. Then find the value of $(2n^2+1)^2$

I found this question on telegram, with no solution. The poster wrote that this problem was apparantly meant for a competitive exam. There were also other people demanding for the solution, but in vain.

My attempt:

I can't even draw the diagram correctly, let alone solving the integral. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**In the problem, there is one integral in numerator and two in denominator, in addition.**

Comment: It would be nice if you could parse the terminology into a clear cut equation of the hyperbola, such as: $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

Comment: It seems an IMO problem or something like that. Atonishtingly difficult for me.

Comment: Now posted to MO.